# Getting D3 static tree diagrams by using force layout

Tags: d3.js, tree, force-layout

Please help me create diagrams like these: (I tried, but stuck on setting up `force layout`)

[image]

Here is [an implementation of ordinary D3 tree with "FISH" data](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/gkDa3/):

[image]

The challenge is: How do we get diagram below from diagram above? (but without "hardcoding" of coordinates; this means, there is a need for applying force layout, or similar method)

[image]

Comment: I'll attach some code later during the day...

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Comment: At first look, I would say that the trick would be to not display any of the circles that you will be creating for the nodes, with the detail that you would make the non-leaf nodes big and label them (with some text anchored to the center of the circle), and make the leaf nodes rather small and attach text elements to them (under a g group, of course). And hopefully, this German sentence makes sense.

Comment: @pawelmhm you should make your comment an answer

Comment: Hey @VividD.  There's a couple things going on here.  One is using straight lines instead of a curve created by d3.svg.diagonal.  That should be straightforward for you to figure out, you just need to use a polar-coordinates to Cartesian function.  The second is getting the leaf nodes to fan out from their parent.  I would do that as a distinct layout method, just rotating by index and translating outwards after laying out the branches based on size.  If you don't get it figured out by Sunday, tag me in a comment and I'll give it a go.

Comment: @VividD any code yet?

Comment: @ernd enson, I think I have design for complete solution. Code, I experimented here and there. Not ready for publishing here. Font is Neutraface. I have a nice way to initialize radial tree diagram first, and then... booooom... switch to force layout, with root node remaining in the center. I need to play more with charge and gravity and custom forces. Circular arrangement of leaves is critical. Final stage of solution IMHO needs manual adjustment of positions of nodes of depth 1. Unfortunately, I don't have much time these days for this, but will post something as soon as I have time.

Comment: @VividD nice to hear - i would love to see your implementation :D

Answer (score -1):

Complete tutorial [can be found here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550).

You should also read documentation for [tree layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout).